# I cannot read from serial port until I login

Tags: ssh, serial-port, serial-console

I have a python script that reads from serial:

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttymxc0", 115200)

for i in range(100):
    with open("test", 'w') as f:
        f.write(s.read_all())
```

The serial port is receiving data from an external device and everything works fine when I manually run it via SSH. However, when I try to make this script run at boot with systemd or rc.local, it first reads a bunch of 0 bytes and then nothing. I tried to initialize the serial port with xonxoff=False and dtr=False but the result is the same. This script runs on a Linux build with serial console disabled. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: I vaguely remember NXP serial ports to be a bit special, so you might need to prepare your port with `stty` (not `setserial`)

Comment: What are the parameters that I have to check with stty?

Comment: don't know your hardware, can't tell you!

Comment: It's a board equipped with a NXP module running YOCTO linux.
Could it be a DMA problem?